# DTLminforcolumn not working with empty rows

Tags: datatool

I use datatool to parse a CSV file. I want to use the makro \DTLminforcolumn to calculate the minimum value of a column. This works fine if every row has a value, but not so much, if there are empty rows. How can I tell datatool to ignore empty rows?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{example1.csv}
title;value
test1;1
test2;
test3;3
test4;2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{example2.csv}
title;value
test1;1
test2;2
test3;3
test4;4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \DTLsetseparator{;}%
    \DTLloaddb{a}{example1.csv}
    \DTLminforcolumn{a}{value}{\minValueFirstExample}
    
    \DTLsetseparator{;}%
    \DTLloaddb{b}{example2.csv}
    \DTLminforcolumn{b}{value}{\minValueSecondExample}
    
    Min Value1: \minValueFirstExample\\ %Should be 1 and not 2
    Min Value2: \minValueSecondExample %Is correct
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines after loading the `datatool` package.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd\DTLminforcolumn{%
  \DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}%
}{%
  \ifdefempty\DTLthisval{}{\DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}}%
}{}{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd\DTLminforcolumn{%
  \DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}%
}{%
  \ifdefempty\DTLthisval{}{\DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}}%
}{}{}
\begin{document}
    \DTLlistskipemptytrue
    \DTLsetseparator{;}%
    \DTLloaddb{a}{example1.csv}
    \DTLminforcolumn{a}{value}{\minValueFirstExample}
    
    \DTLsetseparator{;}%
    \DTLloaddb{b}{example2.csv}
    \DTLminforcolumn{b}{value}{\minValueSecondExample}

    \noindent
    Min Value1: \minValueFirstExample\\ %Should be 1 and not 2
    Min Value2: \minValueSecondExample %Is correct
\end{document}
```

**Explanation.** `\DTLminforcolumn` is defined in `datatool.sty` as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\DTLminforcolumn}[3]{% #1 database, #2 col name, #3 return value
  \def#3{}%                                   #3 := ""
  \DTLifdbexists{#1}{%                        if database #1 exists:
     \@sDTLifhaskey{#1}{#2}{%                   if column #2 exists in db #1:
       \@sdtlforcolumn{\DTLthisval}{#1}{#2}{%     for DTLthisval in column #2:
         \ifdefempty{#3}{%                          if #3 == "":
           \let#3\DTLthisval%                         #3 := DTLthisval
         }{%                                        else:
           \DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}%              #3 := min(#3,DTLthisval)
         }%                                     
       }% 
     }{%                                        else:
       \PackageError{datatool}{Key `#2' %         raise exception
       doesn't exist in database `#1'}{}%
     }%
  }{%                                         else:
    \PackageError{datatool}{Data base %         raise exception
    `#1' doesn't exist}{}%
  }%
}
```

`\DTLmin` returns 'empty' if any of the two numbers is empty. So, when `\DTLthisval` happens to be empty (because the field in the column is empty), the minimum computed so far in `#3` will be reset to 'empty', as it was before the loop started.

To change this behavior we have to make sure that the minimum is only computed for non-empty fields. Therefore we use `\patchcmd` from the package `xpatch` to replace in `\DTLminforcolumn` the line

```
\DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}%     #3 := min(#3,DTLthisval)
```

by

```
\ifdefempty\DTLthisval{%          if DTLthisval == "":
}{%                               else:
  \DTLmin{#3}{#3}{\DTLthisval}%     #3 := min(#3,DTLthisval)
}%
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you explain me what this does? Btw, I found out, that \DTLminforkeys also works correctly.

Comment: @SCM I have added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gernot